# Movie about a creature from space that inhabits a man's body and gives him the ability to regenerate

Tags: story-identification, movie

Many years ago I saw a VHS movie; it might be 80s or 90s.

It was about some creatures coming from space. In the first scene a husband and wife saw their space ship somewhere.

The creature came out and jumped inside the man's mouth and gave him ability to rebuild his body. For example, in a bar/cafe someone shot his hand and he grew another hand. In another scene he fell under a train and was destroyed but regenerated from one hand left of his body.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This is sort of a common attribute in sci fi when an alien invades your body, that you are stronger or regenerate, etc. so more details would indeed help. How did the story end? Were there other aliens involved -- there is a movie called The Hidden with the parasite being pursued by like alien police.

Comment: How that alien creature looks like?
Was man conrolled by the creature? Was that man protagonist or antagonist afterwards?